# How to fix it googleMap flutter web

Tags: flutter, google-maps

This URL refresh every time when run and debug
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to the port, you can set it using `flutter run --web-port <your_port_number>`

If you are using VSCode, you can create `launch.json` file in `.vscode` folder.

The contents of the `launch.json` can be like this:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run (Debug)",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": [
                "--web-port",
                "8686",
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

In you Google Cloud Console, you can just pass the referrer as `http://localhost:8686`